# Handling sequenced network packets

Tags: c#, networking, dictionary, buffer, packets

I have an application that will be reading sequenced packets from a udp connection. These messages need to be stored in some form of buffer with their sequence numbers for lookup.

This 'buffer' is serviced by another thread that removes the message and handles it. If a sequence number is missed, I have stop the service thread and then re-request the message on another TCP connection. Once it arrives, I want to plonk it back into the buffer, and the service thread can continue.

**So I need : insertions by key, removals by lowest key. The key will be a numerical incrementing number such as 1,2,3,4 so it makes it a bit easier to keep track of the highest number, as the key can thus be incremented/decremented, avoiding the need to sort the datastructure.**

`My one plan is to use a Dictionary as the buffer, which makes for a simple solution`

`My other solution uses a set up two queues`

`Suggestion by zmbg to use SortedList - I am concerned about performance, as hashing would provide faster lookup and insert not?`

**My questions are:**

- Basically I'm looking for pitfalls in terms of memory or performance using a dictionary for this solution. The machine that will run it doesn't have too much memory, but throughput performance has a slightly higher priority.
- If this application is running all day, would there be any memory related issues when using the dictionary?
- Does anyone have any thoughts on this or alternative implementation of this procedure. I have  to decide on a design, but I cannot test different solutions for performance as I don't quite have enough time, so I thought I'd try a theoretical gathering of ideas and merit of implementation ideas before I start.

Comment: You really have a service that uses *both* UDP and TCP? That's sounds weird. Why don't you just use TCP in the first place, if you need all packets and you need them in order?

Comment: Also, are you using .Net 4.0?

Comment: @svick I am using .Net 2.0, but if a solution requires .Net 4.0 I can look at possibly upgrading conformance of all code to .Net 4.0.

Comment: I am not providing the UDP/TCP setup up, I am connecting to another service.

Comment: How many packets do you expect in the queue at the same time?

Comment: At this stage I am not sure. I'm guessing around 5000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to implement my own Queue with a Dictionary backing it.

Dictionary provides the insertion and removal performance I am looking for, and pondering too much over small performance issues prematurely is not going to get me nowhere.

Keeping track of the lowest number only is fine, I will not go into too much detail further.

Answer (score 1):

I think a dictionary isn't right here, not because of memory issues, but because it just doesn't make a lot of sense. I would with a sorted list, where it's easy to remove the first elements, and it's also easy to add elements in the middle.

A dictionary doesn't have the notion of 'first'.

The memory consumption will be more or less the same (the data will take up most of the memory, not the overhead of a dictionary or list), and performance of a list will be better.

Your operations on the data structure are: Add a packet at the end of the buffer, remove a buffer from the beginning of the buffer, if there's a missing packet, stop all your operations, ask for a retransmit, and then add it - probably to the beginning of the buffer (because that's how you realized a packet is lost).

A .NET List is actually implemented over an array, which isn't the best of choices, but you can use a LinkedList - that's perfect for what you need.

Comment: Why would a list not be enough if there is a lot of packet loss?

Comment: That depends on how would you use the List. If you used something like `List.RemoveAt(0)`, then that has bad performance for big lists. Implementing a circular buffer, on the other hand, should be pretty fast. In any case, performance probably doesn't matter much, because the list won't contain many items.

Comment: Adding things to the middle of the list can be inefficient, but actually you don't have to. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Performance on SortedLists are much slower from what I ahve been able to gather online, and this is an issue for me.

Comment: Use a simple LinkedList. All your operations are O(1)

Comment: I don't get how you think insertions AND lookups based on a sequence number is O(1) in a linked list...

Comment: Because his lookups are the front of the list. He's essentially using a queue here.